# Vim: Show the index of tabs in the tabline

Tags: vim, tabs, layout

Lets say I opened `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3a.txt` and `file3b.txt` such that the tabline (the thing on the top) looks like this:

```
file1.txt  file2.txt  2 file3a.txt
```

(Note how `file3b.txt.` is missing because it is shown in a split, in the same tab as `file3a.txt`)

To move more quickly between tabs (with `<Number>gt`), I would like each tab to display its index, along the filename. Like so:

```
1:<file1.txt>  2:<file2.txt>  3:<2 file3a.txt>
```

The formatting (the angle braces in particular) are optional; I just want the index to appear there (the `1:`, `2:` and so on).

No clues on `:h tab-page-commands` or google whatsoever.

Comment: Update: [This](https://github.com/mkitt/tabline.vim) plugin might be helpful. I think it was created much after this question was answered so it does not appear in any of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at:

```
:help 'tabline'
:help setting-tabline
```

And if you have "e" in your 'guioptions' setting:

```
:help 'guitablabel'
```

Comment: That got me on the right track. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @bitmask could your perhaps provide your solution? Heptite, could you amend your answer?

Comment: @wmarbut  use this [plugin](https://github.com/mkitt/tabline.vim), it's wonderful.

Comment: Agreed. Extremely disappointing when solution is apparently "found" but not provided and everyone has to spend the same amount of time digging through docs and writing the same configs.

Comment: Everybody for himslef!

Answer (score 13):

put this in your vimrc

```
" Rename tabs to show tab number.
" (Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927952/whats-implementation-of-vims-default-tabline-function)
if exists("+showtabline")
    function! MyTabLine()
        let s = ''
        let wn = ''
        let t = tabpagenr()
        let i = 1
        while i <= tabpagenr('$')
            let buflist = tabpagebuflist(i)
            let winnr = tabpagewinnr(i)
            let s .= '%' . i . 'T'
            let s .= (i == t ? '%1*' : '%2*')
            let s .= ' '
            let wn = tabpagewinnr(i,'$')

            let s .= '%#TabNum#'
            let s .= i
            " let s .= '%*'
            let s .= (i == t ? '%#TabLineSel#' : '%#TabLine#')
            let bufnr = buflist[winnr - 1]
            let file = bufname(bufnr)
            let buftype = getbufvar(bufnr, 'buftype')
            if buftype == 'nofile'
                if file =~ '\/.'
                    let file = substitute(file, '.*\/\ze.', '', '')
                endif
            else
                let file = fnamemodify(file, ':p:t')
            endif
            if file == ''
                let file = '[No Name]'
            endif
            let s .= ' ' . file . ' '
            let i = i + 1
        endwhile
        let s .= '%T%#TabLineFill#%='
        let s .= (tabpagenr('$') > 1 ? '%999XX' : 'X')
        return s
    endfunction
    set stal=2
    set tabline=%!MyTabLine()
    set showtabline=1
    highlight link TabNum Special
endif
```

Comment: Do you know what `'%999XX'` means here?

Comment: Since this one works for both terminal and gvim, I think its the best solution. Take my upvote, sir.

Answer (score 7):

On the [wikia page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Show_tab_number_in_your_tab_line) you may find at least two (the ones I tested) which give you the tab indices, and one of them produces the number of windows inside each buffer which have edits.

Here is the result of my modifications on the one that produces the count of edited buffers, the change I made was to make the highlight value of the count consistent with the rest of the tab:

[image]

```
set showtabline=1  " 1 to show tabline only when more than one tab is present
set tabline=%!MyTabLine()  " custom tab pages line
function! MyTabLine() " acclamation to avoid conflict
    let s = '' " complete tabline goes here
    " loop through each tab page
    for t in range(tabpagenr('$'))
        " set highlight
        if t + 1 == tabpagenr()
            let s .= '%#TabLineSel#'
        else
            let s .= '%#TabLine#'
        endif
        " set the tab page number (for mouse clicks)
        let s .= '%' . (t + 1) . 'T'
        let s .= ' '
        " set page number string
        let s .= t + 1 . ' '
        " get buffer names and statuses
        let n = ''      " temp string for buffer names while we loop and check buftype
        let m = 0       " &modified counter
        let bc = len(tabpagebuflist(t + 1))     " counter to avoid last ' '
        " loop through each buffer in a tab
        for b in tabpagebuflist(t + 1)
            " buffer types: quickfix gets a [Q], help gets [H]{base fname}
            " others get 1dir/2dir/3dir/fname shortened to 1/2/3/fname
            if getbufvar( b, "&buftype"  ) == 'help'
                let n .= '[H]' . fnamemodify( bufname(b), ':t:s/.txt$//'  )
            elseif getbufvar( b, "&buftype"  ) == 'quickfix'
                let n .= '[Q]'
            else
                let n .= pathshorten(bufname(b))
            endif
            " check and ++ tab's &modified count
            if getbufvar( b, "&modified"  )
                let m += 1
            endif
            " no final ' ' added...formatting looks better done later
            if bc > 1
                let n .= ' '
            endif
            let bc -= 1
        endfor
        " add modified label [n+] where n pages in tab are modified
        if m > 0
            let s .= '[' . m . '+]'
        endif
        " select the highlighting for the buffer names
        " my default highlighting only underlines the active tab
        " buffer names.
        if t + 1 == tabpagenr()
            let s .= '%#TabLineSel#'
        else
            let s .= '%#TabLine#'
        endif
        " add buffer names
        if n == ''
            let s.= '[New]'
        else
            let s .= n
        endif
        " switch to no underlining and add final space to buffer list
        let s .= ' '
    endfor
    " after the last tab fill with TabLineFill and reset tab page nr
    let s .= '%#TabLineFill#%T'
    " right-align the label to close the current tab page
    if tabpagenr('$') > 1
        let s .= '%=%#TabLineFill#%999Xclose'
    endif
    return s
endfunction"
```

Comment: Your script is better than the other one since it retains the part where the tab shows if the file has been edited. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I've been using the tabline from the [`airline`](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline) plugin, but to be honest, this old tabline that I came up with is a lot more functional...

Answer (score 6):

The **[tabline plugin](https://github.com/mkitt/tabline.vim)** is a vim plugin that implements requested functionality and won't blow out your vimrc. Simply install, and restart vim.

To install:

```
cd /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mkitt/tabline.vim/master/plugin/tabline.vim
```

or use a plugin manager.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for **minimum required information** and suggestions on how to recommend software on Super User.  To keep your answer useful even if the provided link(s) breaks these details should be edited into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

For GUI-based Vim (Gvim on Linux, MacVim on Mac, etc), put this in your `.gvimrc`:

```
set guitablabel=%N:%M%t " Show tab numbers
```

Some tips on actually using the displayed numbers:

- `Ngt` will switch to tab `N`. For example, `3gt` goes to tab 3.
- `:tabm2` moves the current tab to appear **after** tab 2.

  - To move this tab to the first position, use `:tabm0`
  - To move this tab to the last position, just use `:tabm`